# Is a constant function periodic?

Tags: functions, periodic-functions

Can we regard a constant function "$f(x)=\text{constant}$" to be a periodic function? If yes, what is its period?

Comment: Yes, and anything.

Comment: See Sassatelli last paragraph. A constant function is a somewhat trivial example of a periodic function with any period.

Comment: You just deleted a similar "question". The question was : what do you want to show really ? Is it the Fourier series vs the Fourier transform ?

Comment: Why was this closed? It was stated as being off-topic, but in my opinion is most certainly on-topic.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> *Definition 1:* For $P>0$, a function $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ is *periodic of period* $P$ (or $P$*-periodic*) if $$\forall x\in\Bbb R,\ f(x+P)=f(x)$$ A function is commonly said to be *periodic* if there is some $P>0$ such that $f$ is $P$-periodic.
>
> *Definition 2:* For a periodic function $f$, the *fundamental period* of $f$ is, if existing, the least positive real number $T$ such that $f$ is $T$-periodic. Specifically, if we call $$L=\inf\{ P>0\,:\,\forall x\in\Bbb R,\ f(x+P)=f(x)\},$$ then $f$ has a fundamental period if and only if $L>0$; in which case, $L$ is the fundamental period of $f$.

**Answer to your question:** Constants are periodic functions of any period and, therefore, they do not have a fundamental period.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, a constant function is a periodic function with any **T∈R** as its period (as f(x)=f(x+**T**) always for howsoever small **'T'** you can find).

However, the fundamental period of a constant function is not defined for the above reason.

Answer (score 2):

Nowhere in the definition of a period function is it stated that the function must have a *least* period.

If $f(x) = c$ then for any $p$ we have $f(x+p) = f(x)$.  So $f$ is periodic and $p$ is *a* period.  Obviously any other non-negative value will also be a period.

There is nothing in the definition of periodic function that says that is not allowed.

Comment: Ah... G. Sassatelli beat me by a minute with a good definition.  The idea of a *least* period simply called the "fundamental period".  It does not exist for constant functions.

Comment: For clicks and gigles let $f(x) = 0$ if $x$ is rational.  And $f(x) = 1$ if $x$ is irrational.  Then for any rational $q$, $f(x+q) = f(x)$ so $f(x)$ is also a periodic function that has no fundamental period.  But $f(x) = c $ is the only periodic continuous function that has no fundamental period.  FYI.