# Is the signal u[n] +u[-n] periodic?

Tags: periodic-functions, step-function

In my Signals&Systems book it is written that sum of discrete time unit step function and its time reversal is periodic. 
$x[n]=u[n]+u[-n]$
I just couldn't understand how $\;x[n]\;$ can be periodic even if it has the value 2 at 0 which doesn't recur anywhere else. Maybe I am missing something, I will appreciate any help.

Comment: It is not periodic in general. Let $u$ be 1 at zero and zero everywhere else, for example.

Comment: @Tokugave You are right, $u[n]+u[-n]$ is not periodic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$x[n]=u[n]+u[-n]$$ isn't periodic because of the reason stated by OP.

But if $$x[n]={u[n]+u[-n}] \ \forall n\ \ne0$$ and if you define $x[0]=1,$ then it will be a constant function.

And as stated [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2385273/is-a-constant-function-periodic) in the other answer, constant functions are periodic and don't have any fundamental periods.

Comment: These two functions are not different regarding constantness.