# Period of $\sin^{2} x\ + \cos^{2} x$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions, trigonometry, periodic-functions

While I was studying Periodicity of functions I encountered the following problem :

My textbook said that :

> Constant function is a periodic function but its fundamental period doesn't exist

So to check it I assumed $$f(x) = \sin^{2}x + \cos^{2} x$$
$$f(x) = 1$$
Now if I go by definition i.e.

> If $f(x+T) = f(x)$ for some value of T then the smallest value for T is known as fundamental period of $f(x)$

by definition it comes out to be $\frac \pi 2$ but if we go by the constant function it should not exist . So I am confused to what to choose : $\frac \pi 2$ or doesn't exist ?

Comment: "by definition it comes out to be $\frac{\pi}{2}$" this completely unjustified assertion is your problem

Comment: Its answered here: Constants are periodic functions of any period and, therefore, they do not have a fundamental period. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2385273/is-a-constant-function-periodic

Comment: I would definitely say that constant functions were periodic, it's just that they lack a minimal period.  Some non-constant functions share that property:  consider the characteristic function of the rationals.  Any rational is a period for that.  Having a least period is not required by the definition.

Comment: @NilotpalSinha if I give you to find the period of sin^2 x + cos^2 x what will be your answer ? pi/2 or doesn't exist ?

Comment: There is nothing special about $\frac {\pi}2$ as regards your function.  Nothing at all.  It's not clear why you are fixated on it.  Any non-zero real number is a period for a constant function.

Comment: @MokshitArora Its answered in details the link I provided .Pls read it. If you do not understand it, feel free to ask which part you are unable to understand

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is a constant function periodic?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2385273/is-a-constant-function-periodic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The given function $f(x) = \sin^2 x + \cos^2 x$ simplifies to the constant function $f(x) = 1$. This is because of the trigonometric identity $\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x = 1$, which holds for all $x$.

Now, regarding periodicity, a function is called periodic if there exists a non-zero value $T$ such that $f(x + T) = f(x)$ for all $x$. For a constant function, this condition is satisfied for any non-zero value of $T$, as $f(x) = f(x + T)$ for any $x$ and any $T$.

The fundamental period of a function is the smallest positive value of $T$ that satisfies the periodicity condition. However, in the case of a constant function, since any non-zero value of $T$ satisfies the periodicity condition, there is no smallest positive value of $T$. Therefore, the fundamental period of a constant function does not exist.

In your example, the fundamental period of $f(x) = \sin^2 x + \cos^2 x$ does not exist, as it is a constant function. The confusion with $\frac{\pi}{2}$ arises from considering the individual functions $\sin^2 x$ and $\cos^2 x$, which are periodic with period $\pi$. However, their sum, which is the constant function $f(x) = 1$, does not have a fundamental period.

Answer (score 0):

$\dfrac{\pi}{2}$ is not fundamental period of $f$ since we have $0<\dfrac{\pi}{3}<\dfrac{\pi}{2}$ and $f(x+\tfrac{\pi}{3})=f(x)$.

---

Your textbook says, "Constant function is a periodic function but its fundamental period doesn't exist."

According to that,  fundamental period of $f$ doesn't exist because $f$ is a constant function.

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{\pi}{2}$ is a period of $\sin^2x+\cos^2x$

Even $e^{\pi^e}$ is a period of $\sin^2x+\cos^2x$

You get it$?$ Any real number (except $0$) can be the period of $\sin^2x+\cos^2x$